# Can I use Adaptive MCMC in any setting?

Tags: time-series, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

In time series econometrics and finance, most Bayesian authors approximate their models with a Gibbs Sampler, this is especial true for state space models, SV and so forth.  The dimensionality of these problems ranges from 3-20 parameters.

The thing is, that for some of the more complex time series models, I find that writing the Gibbs sampling algorithm, or trying to find out how to use good built-ins to implement it, is much more labor intensive than simply writing a likelihood and prior, taking a good guesstimate for the proposal covariance matrix, and giving the whole thing to a function like `Metro_Hastings` from the library `MHadaptive`, not to mention that you are no longer restricted to conjugate priors.

For these time series models, what are the potential consequences of using Adaptive Metropolis Hastings in place of a Gibbs sampler?

Comment: FYI: there is also other software (e.g. [JAGS](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/) or [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/)) that uses other than Gibbs sampling algorithms and in many cases they are more efficient than pure M-H or Gibbs.

Comment: The Gibbs sampler does not "estimate"a model, but approximates the exact Bayesian estimation of this model.

Comment: @xian I changed it.